# Simple MySQL query is blocking when adding ORDER BY with LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, query-optimization, innodb, sql-limit

I have a table **tb_profilecomments**:

4,3 GiB -- 8 Million rows total -- InnoDB

with 3 indexes:

[image: Database SHOW INDEX]

The query I run is simple:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_profilecomments
WHERE profilecomment_user_id=6430
ORDER BY profilecomment_id DESC
```

Getting a result in less than 1 second (16.000+ rows).
When I now add `LIMIT 1, 5` to the query then I got to wait more than 2 minutes to get a result.

Don't know what happens in the mysql background why it's slowing down the query so heavily.

When I remove `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` from the query, then everything is fine.

When sorting it by non-indexed `profilecomment_date` column, then it's slow (7 seconds), but not 2 minutes like when sorting and limiting with the indexed primary key `profilecomment_id`.

Do you have any idea what's wrong? A broken index maybe? How to find out? How to fix? ANALYZE TABLE says message "ok".

EXPLAIN **tb_profilecomments**:

[image: EXPLAIN TABLE command]

SHOW CREATE TABLE **tb_profilecomments**:

[image: SHOW CREATE TABLE command]

Result `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tb_profilecomments WHERE profilecomment_user_id=6430 ORDER BY profilecomment_id DESC LIMIT 1, 5`:

[image: EXPLAIN SELECT command]

Comment: Have you used [13.8.2 EXPLAIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html)? This may provide information that can be useful.

Comment: Can you show us the output from `show create table tb_profilecomments` ?  The behavior you are describing seems inconsistent with the structure.

Comment: @wchiquito added result of EXPLAIN TABLE command

Comment: Have you done a [13.8.2 EXPLAIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) or a [13.7.5.6 SHOW COLUMNS Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-columns.html)?.

Comment: @wchiquito It was the EXPAIN syntax

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added output of SHOW CREATE TABLE

Comment: What about `SHOW INDEXES FROM tb_profilecomments` ?  Sorry forgot to ask you this \:-|

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You can see this result in first picture included in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows within an index are very definitely ordered.  `ASC` only.  Even the 5.7 manual page says

> An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order.

MySQL has always had that limitation.  (Upgrading won't help.)

But... That does not stop the code from delivering results in `DESC` order.

That is, MySQL's deficiency of not having DESC indexes rarely matters.  Here is one case where it does matter:  `ORDER BY x ASC, y DESC`.  No `INDEX` can be built (in MySQL) to efficient handle that.

The optimal index for *your* query is

```
INDEX(user_id, comment_id);
```

`user_id` will be used for `WHERE user_id = _constant_`, then `comment_id` will be scanned in reverse order to get the rows you desire.  With or without a `LIMIT`.

But... The index *must* handle *all* of `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY` before `LIMIT` short-circuits execution.  (Otherwise, there is a filesort, tmp table, etc, before `LIMIT` can be applied.)

For the extra-slow queries, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and (if possible), `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`.

Do *not* drop the `PRIMARY KEY` on an InnoDB table!  It is vitally needed.  (OK, drop it if you are replacing it.)

Comment: Hi Rick, just added the result of your suggested EXPLAIN SELECT command, see last picture in question... EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON wasn't possible, syntax error.

Comment: You _need_ `INDEX(profilecomment_user_id, profilecomment_id)`

Comment: Should I drop the other indexes? You mentioned, never dropping the primary key/index (profilecomment_id). When now creating a new index, profilecomment_id would be twice indexed, isn't it?

Comment: According to the `SHOW CREATE`, you currently have 2 indexes (not "3" as mentioned earlier); neither of them overlap with the one I propose.  No `DROP`.

Comment: Sorry for my late reaction on this topic. This answer is correct and helped! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

create index on column `profilecomment_id` in decreasing order.

Syntax Format:

```
CREATE [UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
    [index_type]
    ON tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [index_type]

index_col_name:
    col_name [(length)] [ASC | DESC]

index_type:
    USING {BTREE | HASH}
```

Sample example:

```
create table t1(id int(9),name varchar(20),
               [UNIQUE] KEY (id DESC));
```

DESC order will NOT work for primary key. But it will work for `UNIQUE or normal index`.  You may verify on following link:
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddf95/1 &
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c50d/1

Older version ignores `DESC` and keep order `ASC`.
For details kindly refer below url:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html

Comment: I don't think indices have an "order" per se.

Comment: I just know "A" for ASC and "NULL" for no sort order. Can you explain how you would re-create the index with decreasing order?

Comment: @lickmycode : by-default sorting order is ascending. ASC and DESC  order for index is reserved for future enhancement. I should be implemented by now in latest version as per MySQL documentation. Please let me know the version of MySQL you are using.

Comment: MySQL 5.1.73 is the version used

Comment: Would you please give me the syntax based on the table info used in the question instead of copy and paste the mysql documentation? Would be more helpful.

Comment: @lickmycode : its lil old version. Anyway just try it. Just update with `column_name DESC` in your index creation. And let let me know whether it worked.

Comment: I know it's an old version, can't change that for now. Could you provide the full command I should use please? Then I test it now.

Comment: I now added this, but like you said, it seems to be ignored. At least, I don't see any hint of DESC after adding the index :-/

Comment: Okay, mysql 5.1 manual says DESC is valid... how can I confirm it's used?

Comment: @lickmycode : You can spot the difference by looking into `EXPLAIN` plan of both version i.e., with  DESC order and without DESC order index.

Comment: @lickmycode : I found the solution, instead of using primary key if you use `normal or unique index`. it will work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddf95/1 & http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c50d/1

Comment: Sounds promising. Will test it out. What about the 'PRIMARY' index on column (profilecomment_id) I have. Drop it? Can't I just alter it maybe?

Comment: _The chatter in the comments here has multiple errors.  I have tried to rectify them in my 'Answer'._